# ¿Cómo agregar contenido dinámico en Xamarin.forms?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, botón, xamarin.forms

Estoy desarrollando una App en Xamarin.forms y en una de las pantallas, tengo que armar una serie de botones según una lista de clientes que tengo. Como hace poco empecé a desarrollar en Xamarin.forms no tengo mucha idea de cómo funciona.

Este es el código que uso para generar los botones:

```
if (ListaClientes != null && ListaClientes.Count > 0)
{
    StackLayout sl = new StackLayout();

    foreach (var c in ListaClientes)
    {
        ws.BuscarPartesAsync();
        Button btnCliente = new Button();
        btnCliente.Text = c.cmCompanyName;
        btnCliente.Clicked += BtnCliente_Click;
        btnCliente.BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex(AzulHexa);
        btnCliente.TextColor = Color.White;

        //Aquí quiero mostrar mi botón en la pantalla
        sl.Children.Add(btnCliente);
    }
}
```

Como pueden ver el objeto del botón ya está creado, pero no se como agregarlo a la ventana para que puedan verlo los usuarios.

Alguien puede ayudarme?

Comment: Pues dependerá de a que control quieras añadirla, pero imagino que será `control.Children.Add(btnCliente)`

Comment: Esta un tanto cnofusa tu pregunta pero si la e comprendido bien tu preguntas esto usa xaml para crear el boton y fijate bien como esta aquí: `<Button x:Name="nameButton" Clicked="clicked_comoQuierasAki" ></Button>
`
`void clicked_comoQuierasAki(object sender,SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e) {//tu codigo }`

Comment: No, eso no es lo que necesito porque desde el xaml puedo agregar una cantidad específica y en mi caso, no sé cuántos botones voy a tener. 
Tengo un Web Service que me devuelve una lista de clientes, yo en base a esa lista hago el foreach que se ve en la publicación y voy creando un botón por cada elemento de la lista. Pero no puedo hacer que se vea el botón en la pantalla...

Comment: Gracias por el comentario @Pikoh, ahora estoy teniendo otro problema en el proyecto, pero ni bien lo solucione lo pruebo y te aviso!

Comment: Igualmente gracias por tu respuesta!!

Comment: ok lo que tienes que hacer es que la estructura del xaml tiene que ser un listview personalizado hay va estar tu button y cuando cargues la lista personalizada diatónicamente el botón se replica automáticamente

Comment: Ahí edite nuevamente la publicación para que puedas ver cómo estoy creando todo porque no me deja agregarlo en los comentarios...

Comment: Veo que añades el  botón a un StackLayout que creas en ese momento. En lugar de eso, deberías tener un StackLayout ya en tu ventana y añadir los botones a ese, o bien añadir `sl`a la ventana.

Comment: Si, justo ayer me di cuenta de eso y ya lo hice bien!.. funcionó perfectamente, si queres indicalo como respuesta así lo marco... muchas gracias!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema con el código que tienes es que estás creando un nuevo `StackLayout` donde añades el botón. Este `sl` no existe todavía en ningún layout, asi que debes o bien tener un `StackLayout` ya en tu ventana y añadir los botones en el, o bien añadir `sl` a la ventana.

Answer (score 3):

Como comento  el usuario Pikoh , se debe crear previamente el `StackLayout`con el `x:Name="sl"` y este mismo hacerlo referencia para añadir dinamicamente los controles  `sl.Children.Add(control)`

XAML

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                 x:Class="ButtonDemos.BasicButtonClickPage"
                 Title="Basic Button Click">
        <StackLayout x:Name="sl">


        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage>
```

ContentPage

```
public partial class BasicButtonClickPage : ContentPage
{
    public BasicButtonClickPage ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();

     if (ListaClientes != null && ListaClientes.Count > 0)
        {   
            foreach (var c in ListaClientes)
        {
           ws.BuscarPartesAsync();
          Button btnCliente = new Button();
          btnCliente.Text = c.cmCompanyName;
          btnCliente.Clicked += BtnCliente_Click;
          btnCliente.BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex(AzulHexa);
          btnCliente.TextColor = Color.White;

           //Aquí quiero mostrar mi botón en la pantalla
         sl.Children.Add(btnCliente);
      }
    }
  }  

 void BtnCliente_Click(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    Button sender;
}

}
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta pero este tema ya estaba resuelto hace bastante!

Comment: Exacto , la idea es generar una respuesta mas especifica para los 'demas' , yo igual tuve el misma interrogante y el comentario marcado como respuesta no me ayudo, fue un punto en contra mi poca experiencia con xamarin form.

Comment: Perfecto entonces! Mientras mas se pueda ayudar, mejor!

Comment: Gracias por el aporte.. podrias mirar [answer]? las respuestas que son solo codigo, si ningun tipo de explicacion, suelen considerarse de baja calidad. Explica como este codigo soluciona el problema.

Comment: @gbianchi gracias por la sugerencia, acabo de editar la respuesta,saludos

Comment: Perfecto!!! muchas gracias!